# Convert large numbers on the terminal

Tags: bash, numbers

I am writing a bash script to take in some numbers output from a tool, they are numbers, truncated with the "e" notation (I can't remember the correct name for this).

So, it spits out numbers like 1.3684528004e+05 and 1.2815670938e+04.

How can I convert these into their full original number in my bash script; I have the usual binaries at my disposal such as bc and dc etc, this box also has php-cli installed and perl (Ubuntu 10.x).

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: scientific notation? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: Yes that is correct, thanks for that. Specifically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`printf`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#PRINTFREF) built-in:

```
$ x=1.3684528004e+05
$ printf "%f\n" $x
136845.280040
$ y=1.2815670938e+04
$ printf "%f\n" $y
12815.670938
```